# How to create Logger in RESTFUL API for best practice?

Tags: go, logging, logrus

I have made RESTFUL API using GO and existing Module like *ECHO*, *GORM*, *WIRE*, *LOGRUS*, *VIPER*.

But i dont know best practice how to create *Beautiful Logger* for every activity when someone Hit or Consume my endpoint URL in all HTTP Method Request `(GET/POST/PUT/DEL/UPDATE)`. Can someone give me a example or some reference i need to read and try? or sharing your experience about logger in system using GO

*Beautiful Logger* i mean is addition information about who accessing my endpoint like *current environtment*, *UTC Datetime*, *some authorization name*, *some authorization role*, *endpoint*, *http method*, *request body IF Exists*, *http status code*, *http response*, *ip address*, etc.

Logger i want:

> [2022-12-17 00:00:00 UTC] env=development auth_email=patrick@example.example auth_role=admin endpoint={BASE_URL}/users/1 http_method=GET http_request_body={JSON from STRUCT} http_status=200 http_response={JSON from STRUCT} device_ip_address=192.168.1.1 device_os=windows
>
> [2022-12-17 01:00:02 UTC] env=development auth_email=tommy@example.example auth_role=basic endpoint={BASE_URL}/users http_method=GET http_request_body={JSON from STRUCT} http_status=200 http_response={JSON from STRUCT} device_ip_address=192.168.1.1 device_os=ubuntu